# How to create an Empty Application in Xcode without Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode6

`Xcode6` has removed the `Empty Application` template when creating a new project. How can we create an empty application (without Storyboard) in `Xcode6` and above, like in earlier versions?

Comment: http://codefromabove.com/2014/09/xcode-6-removing-storyboards-and-creating-useful-empty-projects/ , a very good tutorial for this

Comment: Read this: http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2015/10/how-to-create-basic-single-view-project.html

Comment: You can create your own project template for Xcode. For your request, you can use template on this site: [https://github.com/elprup/xcode7-project-template](https://github.com/elprup/xcode7-project-template)

Comment: Up to date tutorial with iOS9 and Xcode 7: https://medium.com/frozen-fire-studios/start-your-xcode-project-without-a-storyboard-fb7009f43c8f

Answer (score 269, accepted):

There is no option in `XCode6` and above versions for directly creating an Empty Application as in `XCode5` and earlier. But still we can create an application without `Storyboard` by following these steps:

1. Create a `Single View Application`.
2. Remove `Main.storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.xib` (select them, right-click, and choose to either
   remove them from the project, or delete them completely).
3. Remove "Main storyboard file base name" and "Launch screen interface
   file base name" entries in `Info.plist` file.
4. Open AppDelegate.m, and edit applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions so that it looks like this:

Swift 3 and above:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool 
    {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

Swift 2.x:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
    {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

Objective-C:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: I like to keep `LaunchScreen.xib` and the corresponding `Info.plist` entry. Without it, the app will not take up the entire screen size on larger iPhones, which is ugly.

Comment: I like to keep the Storyboard, myself. It's convenient for creating various stuff, but I need to do the initial setup without relying on storyboards.

Comment: Maybe a bug in Xcode 7 I was not able to remove Main.storyboard at all from the project information settings screen. I used Xcode 5 empty application template as mentioned by @Silentwarrior.

Comment: Unless you manually install a root ViewController, this answer generates a runtime error in XCode7: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

Comment: Please add this Code also :
    self.window.rootViewController= [[ViewController alloc]init];
in your AppDelegate.m under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Or else you will get the following error : 
'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

Comment: when using this approach, `AutoLayout` seems to be disabled. any idea what I can do to enable it again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173367/autolayout-without-usage-of-storyboards-or-interface-builder

Comment: I used xcode 8 beta 2 and able to create Xibs using Akhil KC steps.
But you are missing Defaults image

Default Images for iPhone:
Default-568h@2x.png
Default-iPhone6.png
Default-iPhone6Plus.png
Default.png
Default@2x.png

iPad :
Default-Portrait~ipad.png (768x1024px)
Default-Landscape~ipad.png (1024x768px)
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png (1536x2048px)
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png (2048x1536px)

Comment: You can also use ".white" for the color on Swift 3 ;-)

Comment: You also need to add ``#import "ViewController.h"`` at the top of AppDelegate.m, after ``#import "AppDelegate.h"``

Comment: When running in the simulator, I get: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A441306A-8CA5-4FCD-98C5-8DFAFBFF1E3E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/63E53C13-3677-44C2-8BEF-61FEAB169010/Totally Empty.app> (loaded)' with name 'EmptyViewController''`

Answer (score 31):

A simple approach would be to copy the `XCode 5`'s `Empty Application` template to `XCode`'s templates directory.

You can download `XCode 5`'s `Empty Application` template from [**here**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65674657/Empty%20Application.xctemplate.zip), then unzip it and copy to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/iOS/Application` directory.

P.S this approach works with swift as well!

**Edit**
As suggested by @harrisg in a comment below, You can place the above mentioned template in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/iOS/Application/` folder so that it may be available even if Xcode gets updated.
And if there is no such directory present, then you might have to create this directory structure: `Templates/Project Templates/iOS/Application/` in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/`

Using this simple approach i'm able to create an `Empty Application` in `XCode 6`. (Screenshot attached below)

[image: Xcode Empty Application Template]
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. As a note you will need to replace this template after Xcode updates.

Comment: If you put it into ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/iOS/Application/ it won't have to be replaced each time Xcode updates

Comment: @harrisg couldn't find this directory in Yosemite. Can you confirm its presence? Thanks

Comment: This approach works with Xcode 7.1, however the LaunchScreen.storyboard is created that some may not want.  I ended up using it as it does not interfere with my manually created views.

Comment: Remember to unzip the file into the directory, copying is not enough.

Answer (score 17):

There are a few more steps that you need to do:

1. To add a prefix file. (If you need it)
2. To add a default launch image, otherwise the app size will be 320x480 on iPhone 5.

So here is a full tutorial:

1. remove Main.storyboard file
2. remove LaunchScreen.xib file
3. remove "Main storyboard file base name" property in Info.plist
4. remove "Launch screen interface file base name" property in Info.plist
5. add "[app name]-Prefix.pch" file to supporting files with contents:

   ```
   #import <Availability.h>

   #ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
   #warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 3.0 and later."
   #endif

   #ifdef __OBJC__
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #endif
   ```
6. add "$SRCROOT/$PROJECT_NAME/[pch file name]" to project settings -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language -> "Prefix Header"
7. add "YES" to to project settings -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language -> "Precompile Prefix Header"
8. open "Image.xcassets" and add LaunchImage
9. build the project, then there will be a warning about missing default launch image, just press on the warning and select to add the default,
   this will add "Default-568h@2x"
   OR - If you want to use splash images from "Images.xcassets", go to the project settings -> TARGETS -> General -> in "Launch Images Source" choose to use asset catalog, it will create a new one, you can choose then, which to use as asset catalog from the existing.
10. implement `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

    ```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    //Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
    ```

Answer (score 16):

Akhils answer is totally correct. For those of us using Swift, it would be like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**Xcode 9.3.1** and **Swift 4**

1. First of all you need delete ***Main.storyboard*** in ***Project navigator*** menu.
2. Then delete row ***Main storyboard file base name*** in ***Info.plist***.
3. And don't forgot delete cell ***Main Interface*** (just remove ***Main***) in your  ***Project Target*** - ***General*** - ***Deployment Info***.
4. After that steps go to ***AppDelegate.swift*** and in function ***didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*** write the next:

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.

       window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
       window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
       window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())

       return true
   }
   ```

**Xcode 11.2.1** and **Swift 5**

1. First of all you need delete **Main.storyboard** in **Project navigator** menu.
2. Then delete row **Main storyboard file base name** in **Info.plist**.
3. And don't forgot delete cell **Main Interface** (just remove **Main**) in your **Project Target - General - Deployment Info**.
4. This step is important and it was not in previous versions of Xcode and Swift. In **Info.plist** go to: **Application Scene Manifest** → **Scene Configuration** → **Application Session Role** → **Item 0** and delete here **Storyboard.name** row.
5. After that steps go to **SceneDelegate** and in function **scene** write the next:

   ```
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
       // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
       // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
       // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
       guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

       window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
       window?.windowScene = windowScene
       window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
       window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 10):

**Update: Swift 5 and iOS 13:**

1. Create a Single View Application.
2. Delete Main.storyboard (right-click and delete).
3. Delete "Storyboard Name" from the default scene configuration in the Info.plist file: [image]
4. Open `SceneDelegate.swift` and change `func scene` from:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```

to

```swift
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).x

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = ViewController()
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have to delete "Main storyboard file base name" from Info.plist, otherwise you'll get the error "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main'"

Answer (score 9):

There is one more step that you need to do:

1)remove Main storyboard file base name in plist file

```
//AppDelegate.h


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *nav;

//AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`enter code here`
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];



    self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    [window setRootViewController:  self.nav];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self setWindow:window];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: there is a bounds problem, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds is printing out :(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0). why is that?

Answer (score 6):

I have the original Empty Application template which was used in Xcode versions prior to Xcode 6. I have uploaded it [here](https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/Xcode-Empty-Application-Template).

You can either download it and paste it in the Xcode template directory manually or install it using the package manager for Xcode, [Alcatraz](https://github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz). Just search for *Xcode Empty Application*.

Answer (score 5):

**Remove the Main.storyboard file**

This can simply be deleted.

**Update the ProjectName-Info.plist file**

Remove the `Main storyboard base file name` key.

**Create a nib file and link to the project’s view controller**

1.Create a nib file (File –> New –> File –> View)

2.Update the `File's Owner's` class to whatever the project’s view
 controller is called

3.Link the `File's Owner's` `view` outlet to the `view` object in the nib file

**Update the app delegate**

1.Import the project’s view controller’s header file

2.Update the application`:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For `Xcode 8` and `Swift 3`.**
Just delete the `.storyboard` file, it will automatically delete the corresponding reference from your `.plist` and in your `AppDelegate.swift` add the following code.

> ```
>     let initialViewController = UIViewController()
>     initialViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
>     window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
>     window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
>     window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
> ```

You can write your own custom ViewCountroller and use in that in `AppDelegate.swift` as your `self.window?.rootViewController`, just replace the UIViewController with your own ViewController in the above code.

Comment: Using Xcode 9.1 & Swift 4 if I simply delete the storyboard file without manually removing the corresponding reference from .plist I get an error "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle". Seems that I must remove the reference manually.

Answer (score 3):

I am using XCode6 Beta & I searched for another solution of this problem by adding Empty template from XCode5.x.x to XCode6 Beta.

For this right click on XCode5.x.x in Applications click 'Show Package Content' and copy 'Empty Application.xctemplate' from given path

Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Application

Now quit the Window & open given path for XCode6

Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/iOS/Application/

Paste 'Empty Application.xctemplate' inside Application folder.  Now restart XCode6 by quiting & create new project. You will get 'Empty Application' option.

Now when I am creating new Empty project,a .pch file automatically added in project (Which we have to add manually in XCode6)

Hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Or just use one of the previous Beta to create it, and continue on the latest version after.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already explained how to get rid of the storyboard, so I will skip on that one here. This is how I prefer to do it in my code with less optional chaining (written in Swift 3.1):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.backgroundColor = .white
    window.rootViewController = MyRootViewController()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window = window

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

update on Xcode 11 and ios 13. After you have everything set but still see a black screen, it's because the life cycle is handled by UISceneDelegate and when you create a new project, it will auto-generate UISceneDelegate.m and UISceneDelegate.h. To go back to the old days before we get used to UISceneDelegate. following steps could help:

1. delete Application Scene Manifest in plist.
2. delete Application Scene Manifest.h and Application Scene Manifest.m
3. delete code under #pragma mark - UISceneSession lifecycle in APPdelegate.m
4. add @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow * window; in APPdelegate.h