# Beginner: XCode 6 - Says base sdk missing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I was trying to do the ToDOList project explained in the tutorial from Apple "Start developing iOS app Today". I downloaded the XCode 6 and created a new "Empty Application". The IDE looks different than how it is in the tutorial, it doesn't give me the option to choose the target device. Also, there was no code files created upon creating the project. I also see an error that says "Base SDK missing". Can anyone tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Try creating a new application using a different template, such as the single view one, and see if it builds/runs with no changes.  That should tell if the Xcode installation is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 6 doesn’t have the “Empty Application” template any more. The one I think you used is just called “Empty”, and it creates a project with nothing at all in it. That’s not what you want.

You can start with the “Single View Application” template. If you want to empty it out, follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119006/4130712).