# Error with iPhone 5 resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I've created an empty project as described here:
[How to create an Empty Application in Xcode 6 without Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783282/how-to-create-an-empty-application-in-xcode-6-without-storyboard)

When run in the Simulator on iPhone 5 it returns for [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] 320x480 and if I press the black area around the white window I receive this error:

```
unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: <UIClassicWindow: 0x7a694c80; frame = (0 0; 320 568); userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7a69e570>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7a695260>>
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

This happens with the latest xCode only because it doesn't have an empty application option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide proper launch image for the iPhone 5 resolution.