# The "Empty Application" Is Missing In the Newer Xcode Versions (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, default

In old versions of Xcode, an "Empty Application" would be a project with all the information to build and everything, but no files except the App Delegate would be added.

In the newer versions of Xcode, the "Empty Application" option is no longer the same. Instead of creating a project with no files but the App Delegate, it creates *nothing at all*! You either have to drag in other files pre-made, or you have to create ***all*** the files, including the App Delegate and all of it's once "default" functions.

How would I get the previous version of "Empty Application"? "Single View Application" is a little different, but nothing else seems to be similar.

Comment: The "Single View" is the closest you will get. Just delete the main storyboard.

Comment: What's your end goal? The single view template is pretty good; just delete what you don't need (such as the main storyboard).

Comment: What language are we talking about? Detailed instructions would depend on that.

Comment: @rmaddy – What about the App Del. default code differing?

Comment: I'm going to tell you all about that. Just tell me what language you want!

Comment: @matt I'm using Objective-C, and I'll edit the question to show that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an Empty Application in Xcode 6 without Storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783282/how-to-create-an-empty-application-in-xcode-6-without-storyboard)

Answer (score 1):

> How would I get the previous version of "Empty Application"

You would have to make it for yourself by paring down the Single View template-based project.

So, for Objective-C:

1. Delete the storyboard.
2. Edit the target and delete "Main" where it asks for the storyboard name. Hit Tab to make this change "stick".
3. Delete the view controller files.
4. Make a new view controller and (optionally) a *.xib* paired with it, to give yourself a starting place. Let say it's called MyViewController.
5. Delete everything in the App Delegate implementation of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and replace it with:

   ```
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   self.window.rootViewController = [MyViewController new];
   self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
   ```

Comment: Answer my question about the language and I'll provide more info. I'm just paused, waiting for you!

Comment: Do all this.  Or... take the hint.  Apple wants people using storyboards.

Comment: Or just download this project as a starting place: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch06p236manualViewController/ch19p575manualViewController

Comment: Thanks, matt, I'll take this into consideration. I may note this as accepted if I don't find any better answers :)

Comment: You hardly can get a better answer, since the steps I have just outlined are precisely what is necessary to go from what the Single View template gives you to what the Empty template used to give you. The difference is only that the Empty template has no view controller - but that is now illegal, so my instructions did not suggest going that far.