# AutoLayout without usage of Storyboards or Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, storyboard, pure-layout

I am building an app where I want to completely avoid using Storyboard and Interface Builder in general, so all UI should be specified in code. I am using [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout), a nice API for configuring `AutoLayout` constraints.

However, my issue is that it seems like `AutoLayout` is disabled when not using Interface Builder. `updateViewConstraints`, the method where I put the layout according to the recommendation given by the `PureLayout` author, is not called at all.

Just to give a bit more info about my setup:

- deleted `Main.storyboard` and removed the entry from my `Info.plist`
- manually setup `self.window` in `AppDelegate.m` and added `UINavigationController` with `MainMainController` as `rootViewController`

As mentioned, my main issue is that `updateViewConstraints` does not get called on `MainViewController` but the UI elements are all displayed with the `frame`s that I passed to them during initilization.

**Note**: It seems to me like I just need to enable some flag somewhere to mimic the checkbox from Interface Builder with which you can indicate whether you want to use `AutoLayout`.

[image]

#### MainViewController.m

```
@interface MainViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *startButton;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL didSetupConstraints;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.startButton];
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
}

- (UIButton *)startButton
{
    if (!_startButton) {
        UIButton *startButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        CGRect startButtonFrame = CGRectMake(75.0, 75.0, 250.0, 44.0);
        startButton.frame = startButtonFrame;
        [startButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [startButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        _startButton = startButton;
    }
    return _startButton;
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    NSLog(@"Update view contraints");
    if (!self.didSetupConstraints) {
        [self.startButton autoCenterInSuperview];
        self.didSetupConstraints = YES;
    }
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}

@end
```

Comment: I think this library use `updateConstraints` method for UIView subclasses and `updateViewConstraints` for View Controllers. That may be the issue that you are expecting a different method in View Controller to get execute.

Comment: Is your views laying out as per the constraints you set. Have you set translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO?

Comment: @Gandalf: sorry my bad, I was actually referring to `updateViewConstraints` not `updateConstraints`, will update this in my post

Comment: @BharatModi yes, in `viewDidLoad`, I set: `[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`. then I just simply try to center a button, with this button I also do `[startButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`

Comment: show some actual code, the library sets the translate value for you when you ask it to apply some constraint

Comment: @Wain sure, I updated the post with the relevant code. I think the issue might be related to PureLayout then, because I am not setting the constraints manually using Apple's API but rather I install them through the library. Note that I used the same code in an IB based project (with an empty View Controller) and it worked.

Comment: generally the view controllers view doesn't set itself to not translate the mask, it's the superview / parent controller who decides to do that... Try instead just calling `setNeedsLayout` at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work with `[self.view setNeedsLayout];`. I also added `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` right after, but this didn't help either.

Comment: If you are using constraints you should not be using frames ideally. And `translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` has to be set to `false` before adding it to the subview.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you wouldn't use Interface Builder and Auto Layout. The reason I ask is your frame values are hard coded which means the button will be the same size on an iPhone 4s as it is on an iPhone 6s Plus. I'm not having a go at you i am just curious.