# I am not using storyboard AT ALL but I am still getting this error

Tags: ios, swift

I am not using main.storyboard at all and making everything through code, but I get this error with this code in my app delegate.

`Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?`

```
var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let rootView = HomeCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController = rootView
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Did you add a view controller to the storyboard? Even if you don't want to use the storyboard, you should a dummy view controller that points your class

Comment: Yup just tried that and it worked. @ridvankucuk

Comment: @ridvankucuk Thats not really needed if done right.

Comment: @joethemow have you got your answer?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani yes.

Comment: so basically you have to accept your appropriate answer..!!

Comment: The comment by @ridvankucuk is the one that solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

If you are not planning on using the storyboard you need to still make some configurations in the project file to let the Xcode know. Under target -> Deployment info you can see a setting for Main Interface, set it as blank then it will not look for the entry point in the storyboards.

[image]

Also, when you are doing everything in code, `UIWindow` instance needs to be instantiated and made visible which allows you to start presenting view controllers.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let viewController = TestViewController()

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can just delete the key from your .plist file `Main storyboard file base`and run it again.**

Also if you are getting the black screen you have to setup window by `self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` like above answer.

Comment: He has not set a window, if he does that he would probably end up with a black screen.

Comment: Yes, You are right !! thanks for your recommendation, but he clearly, ask `I am not using storyboard AT ALL but I am still getting this error`

Comment: So that is a solution of error, not the black screen.

Comment: Well yes you are right  :) But he's probably ok with having a dummy storyboard and a view controller :D

Comment: Okay, but I also update my answer by pointing out your answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

Above my comment, adding an answer. If you are using a storyboard which is dummy for you at this point, you should add a View Controller to your `UIStoryboard`. If you want to remove your `UIStoryboard`, you can still continue without it. In stackoverflow its been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119006/3581421).