# Xcode single project without storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, appdelegate

i was trying to read the big nerd ranch book for ios 7. 
I know it's old but it has very interesting topic and i believe its one of the best written and the best book for learning.

The problem is that i use xcode 6.1 and the templates are totally different. I would also want to translate their Objective-c code into Swift.

The translation part was easy but i got a major issue in doing something probably silly.

This is my code

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var firstframe:CGRect = CGRectMake(160, 240, 100, 150)
        var firstView:HypnoView = HypnoView(frame:firstframe)

        firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.window?.addSubview(firstView)


        return true
    }
}
```

HypnoView

```
import UIKit

class HypnoView: UIView {

    var frameView:CGRect = CGRectNull



    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        frameView = frame
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


}
```

This is the error i get

2014-11-07 20:32:41.408 Hypno[7987:450667] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle  (loaded)'

the app still look for the main storyboard file, but i can't find where it's linked... how can i fix this so i can just start with my own ViewController, without eventually using storyboard? where it's the code that should've been in the app delegate that loads everything? thanks

Comment: You may be interested to read the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24046898/2708650

Answer (score 2):

Remove "Main storyboard file base name" key from info.plist

Answer (score 1):

Click on your project's root folder, General tab, Main Interface (the storyboard is listed here).