# RootView navigation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, ios8

I am an Objectie-C developer. for the root view navigation i used the below code in Objectie-c

```
 FirstViewController *fvc=[[FirstViewController alloc]init];
 UINavigationController *nv=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:fvc];
 self.window.rootViewController=nv;
```

for my new project I am making it in swift.I just want to make RootView navigation from AppDelegate.swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

 var rootVie: FirstViewController = FirstViewController()  // this is allocation method in swift

 if let window = self.window{
        window.rootViewController = rootVie
 }

 return true
}
```

need referene use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046898/how-do-i-create-a-new-swift-project-without-using-storyboards)

Comment: have a happy day my friend

Answer (score 2):

Check below code. first we create window. then alloc init viewcontroller. and then alloc navigation controller with rootcontroller as viewcontroller. and Window's root controller as navigation controller.

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navC : UINavigationController?
var vc:ViewController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    // alloc init window
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    // view controller
    self.vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil);

    // create navigation controller with root = vc.
    self.navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.vc!);
    self.navC?.navigationBar.hidden = true;

    // window's root controller as navigation controller.
    self.window?.rootViewController = self.navC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Maybe this will help you.