# type of 'window' has different optionality than required by protocol 'uiapplicationdelegate' after XCode update to 6.3

Tags: swift

I have this code `var window = UIWindow()` in my AppDelegate. My app is working fine before. After I updated my XCode to 6.3, I can no longer run my iOS app in simulator as I am getting the error

> type of 'window' has different optionality than required by protocol
>   'uiapplicationdelegate'

Comment: Because its now: var window: UIWindow? But you should convert to the latest Swift syntax with Edit -> Convert -> To Latest Swift Syntax to avoid these type of errors.

Comment: The code you typed was the default when I created the app in Swift. I changed to the code above because I am getting an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and used `window! (eg window!.frame = ..`

Comment: Where did you used that code, that window!.frame.... in the AppDelegate?

Comment: I used that code inside `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your contributions. I am not really sure about the reason why suddenly my code `window` declaration is no longer working. To fix it, I used the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25482567/2445717

I revert the declarion of window to the default: `var window: UIWindow?`

and then used the code below for `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    if let window = window {
        window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        window.rootViewController = ViewController()
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, AppDelegate have:

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

instead of

```
var window: UIWindow
```

because it should be nil

You can use a lazy var to make code simply

```
lazy var window: UIWindow? = {
    let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    win.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    win.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.authViewController)
    return win
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cmd-click on the word `UIApplicationDelegate` in the class definition of your code, you will open the protocol definition. I suspect you are using this call:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) {...}
```

and that may have changed in Swift 1.2, but does not seem to be widely documented. If you wrote instead

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow) {...}
```

then you would get the error message you report.

This particular problem is not fixed up by the automated program Daniel Nagy mentions - I ran into a similar issue.

If you have provided that optional function, then just add a `?` after the `UIWindow` in the function definition.