# Missing storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I had a storyboard based application. I deleted the storyboard because I don't need it.

Now when I build my project to simulator it's running but when I try to deploy to a real device it throws this:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle  (loaded)'

I don't want to use storyboard.. where does it try to load "Main" storyboard? where could I remove it?

UPDATE:

```
 var window: UIWindow?
    var mainNavigationController: UINavigationController?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.mainNavigationController = UINavigationController()
        var mainController: UIViewController? = TineLineViewController()
        self.mainNavigationController!.pushViewController(mainController!, animated: false)
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window!.rootViewController = mainController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Thank you now i update my AppDelagate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. The main controller screen is shows up but i have a UISwipeGestureRecognizer which not handling my request.. this is my UISwipeGestureRecognizer:

```
        let postLeft : Selector = "postLeft:"
        let postLeftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: postLeft)
        postLeftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        goToPostButton.addGestureRecognizer(postLeftSwipe)
```

should i change something?

Thank you!

Comment: in your application's plist info file

Comment: awesome thank you! i removed the line from the info.plist but now it's not load the first view controller swift file :) how could i set it? could you please tell me?

Comment: you need to put the code to instantiate and launch this view controller in your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunching:`

Comment: could you send me an example about how to set the initial view controller? :(

Comment: just added answer with a link to another SO question that has some sample code for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first remove the appropriate line from your app's info plist file
2. put the code to instantiate your initial view controller into your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunching:` and set the view controller as the `rootViewController` of your application's main `UIWindow` object (or embed it into a `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController` which again you can set as `rootViewController` of the `UIWindow`). find the code how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046898/how-do-i-create-a-new-swift-project-without-using-storyboards) :)

Comment: Thank you it's working but i updated my question because there is some more errors.. :(

Comment: @solarenqu if the first issue is solved, please accept this answer and post a new question that specifically treats your new issue. you'll be more likely to receive proper help that way!

Comment: i can't ask my question.. :( i have to wait 90 minutes.. do you have any ide about why my UISwipeGestureRecognizer not navigate to the new view?