# Instantiate UINavigationController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to instantiate a `UINavigationController` with a `rootViewController` in my `AppDelegate`. I've looked on this website, but all the examples were from Objective-C or used storyboards (which I'm trying to get away from). 'HomeScreenController` is the root view of the application.

**Edit: this shows up in the console**

```
2015-07-18 14:42:25.376 FastFactsSwift[4749:343495] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' 
- perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
```

How do I fix this?

---

The following code results in just a black screen:

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeScreenController())

    return true
}
...
```

**HomeScreenController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class HomeScreenController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad(){

        super.viewDidLoad()

        var width = self.view.viewWidth
        var height = self.view.viewHeight

        //Add stuff to the view
}
...
```

Why is `HomeScreenController` showing up as a black screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not configuring `AppDelegate` to not use a storyboard.

[How do I create a new Swift project without using Storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046898/how-do-i-create-a-new-swift-project-without-using-storyboards)